# How to get list of branches on a atlassian-stash project using REST call in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, bitbucket-server

I have found stash provide a [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html) to get details from created projects in repository.I am a newbie for stash API.Please let me know that how can i get list branches under a stash project via REST call.

Sample stash project path

```
https://stash.test.local/projects/DEV/repos/central-project/browse
```

Under above **central-project** contains multiple branches like,

1. master
2. feature/test
3. feature/test1

I want to get list of branches via REST call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do it.For REST call i used [rest-assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) in JAVA.

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://stash.test.local";
RestAssured.basePath = "/rest/api/1.0/projects/DEV/repos/central-project/branches";
RestAssured.authentication = RestAssured.preemptive().basic(
                    username, password);
Response response = RestAssured.get();
String branchJSON = response.asString();
```